# How to plus or minus hours in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, laravel-9

I have the following case but don't know how to do it, can anyone help me.

`Clock`
Clock In: 8:00, Clock Out: 17:00 => Total: 9:00

`1st break`
Start Break: 11:00, End Break: 13:00 => Total break1: 2:00

`Second break`
Start Break: 15:00, End Break: 15:30 => Total break2: 0:30

```
$startTime = Carbon::parse('8:00'); 
$endTime = Carbon::parse('17:00');
$duration = $endTime->diffInMinutes($startTime);
$totalminutes += $duration;
dd(date('H:i', mktime(0, $totalminutes)));
Total : 9:00
```

I want to plus the hours of break1 and break2

2:00 + 0:30 = 2:30

and total clock minus total break

9:00 - 2:30 = 6:30

everyone helps me, thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the duration the same way for breaks except that you need to subtract them from the total minutes instead of adding them.

```php
$startTime = Carbon::parse('8:00');
$endTime = Carbon::parse('17:00');

$firstBreakStart = Carbon::parse('11:00');
$firstBreakEnd = Carbon::parse('13:00');

$secondBreakStart = Carbon::parse('15:00');
$secondBreakEnd = Carbon::parse('15:30');

$totalMinutes = $startTime->diffInMinutes($endTime);
$totalMinutes -= $firstBreakStart->diffInMinutes($firstBreakEnd);
$totalMinutes -= $secondBreakStart->diffInMinutes($secondBreakEnd);

dd(date('H:i', mktime(0, $totalMinutes)));
```

Comment: Thank you for the guide, I understood.
Have a nice day!

Comment: In the case of adding many hours together, how will you do it?

`day 1: 08:00
day 2: 07:00
day 3: 07:30

how to sum is 22:30`

please help me, many thanks @roj-vroemen

Comment: Before you convert the total minutes into `08:00` you have the value in full minutes, you can just add them together