# How can sum hours in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, laravel-9

I have the following case but don't know how to do it, can anyone help me.

```
$array = ['day' => 08:00, 'day' => 07:00, 'day' => 07:30] 

how to sum is 22:30
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXvXY.jpg)

please help me, many thanks

Comment: Is this a data column, carbon date or is it something else? This question is fairly vague formulated.

Comment: You asked about this already only a couple hours earlier, [How to plus or minus hours in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71230225/how-to-plus-or-minus-hours-in-laravel)

Comment: it is the total number of hours of working days retrieved from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for something like...

```
$array = ['08:00', '07:00', '07:30'];
```

Try this...

```
  $sum_minutes = 0;
  foreach($array as $time) {
      $explodedTime = array_map('intval', explode(':', $time ));
      $sum_minutes += $explodedTime[0]*60+$explodedTime[1];
  }
  $sumTime = floor($sum_minutes/60).':'.floor($sum_minutes % 60);
```

btw you can't have multiple 'day' keys directly in your array like this question.

Comment: it got error: `ErrorException: Undefined array key 2`

Comment: i updated it a minute ago, did you use the updated code ? and is your array formatted like mine ?

Comment: see here, I have tested my own code in the w3school compiler. It is working fine here. https://pasteboard.co/6X0PwUz5ejsL.png